# iOS memory management confused

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, memory-management

I have a static method in a Utilities class:

```
+ (Division *) getDefaultDivision
{
    Division *defaultDivision = [[Division alloc] init];
    defaultDivision.Id = 0;
    defaultDivision.name = @"Accounting";
    defaultDivision.slug = @"accounting";

    return defaultDivision;
}
```

And in my ViewController I do something like:

```
Division *div = [[Division alloc] init];
div = [Utilities getDefaultDivision];
```

But when I analyze, it says "Potential leak of an object allocated on line x and stored into defaultDivision".

If I use:

```
Division *defaultDivision = [[[Division alloc] init] autorelease];
```

it works once, but when I use it again, it crashes.

Just wondering what the proper thing is to do here?

Comment: Crashlog and Stacktrace would make it easier to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is your real code;

```
Division *div = [[Division alloc] init];
div = [Utilities getDefaultDivision];
```

You're first allocating a Division and saving it in div, then you're getting a new one from getDefaultDivision storing that in div too without releasing the first one.

Comment: Okay so now I am doing Division *div = [Utilities getDefaultDivision]; but regardless, I still get bad_access when I mark autorelease in the method object.

Comment: What are you doing with Division after allocating it? Storing it somewhere for later use? If you store it somewhere unretained and the autorelease happens, you're not in a good place.

Comment: Joachim you solved this for me. I am storing it in the appdelegate.  I missed that retain when assigning.  Works now!  THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how "getDefaultDivision" is implemented, you have a leak in this code:

```
Division *div = [[Division alloc] init];
div = [Utilities getDefaultDivision];
```

Line 1 allocates memory and assigns `div` to point to that memory.  You *must* free this memory at some point.  But after line 2, that becomes impossible, because `div` is now has a new value -- and the pointer to the memory allocated in line 1 is *lost*.  This is a leak.  Until you understand why, you are on thin ice.

As for this method:

```
+ (Division *) getDefaultDivision
{
    Division *defaultDivision = [[Division alloc] init];
    defaultDivision.Id = 0;
    defaultDivision.name = @"Accounting";
    defaultDivision.slug = @"accounting";
    return defaultDivision;
}
```

This is sometimes called a "factory" method -- a static utility method for allocating, initializing, and returning reference to a new instance of a class.  The best practice here is to use autorelease in factory methods.  E.g.:

```
Division *defaultDivision = [[[Division alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Why is it a best practice?  According to Apple's memory management guide, only methods with the following terms in them should return references to objects that the caller is responsible for releasing:

```
alloc, allocWithZone:, copy, copyWithZone:, mutableCopy, mutableCopyWithZone:
```

-- from http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html

Since "getDefaultDivision" is not an "alloc" or "copy" method (it is an accessor method), then it should not return a pointer to an object which the caller must later free to avoid a leak.  Marking the newly allocated returned memory as autorelease is one way to follow this contract.

Comment: Don't forget that functions/methods with the `create` keywoard also are expected to return a retained object, at least I thought this was the case.

Comment: The memory related method naming conventions are why I'm so happy about ARC :)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.  But regardless, when I mark the factory method as autorelease, boom.

Comment: @lef2 I think that is true in Core Foundation, but not Objective C.  CF *functions* with `Create` in them hand you memory that you are responsible for.  Objective C *methods* that start with create do not.  Google (with quotes) "Core Foundation Uses Similar but Different Rules".  Anyway, any time I'm using a function or method with the word "create" in it, I tend to go look up specific documentation on it, just to make sure.  Thanks for the heads up.